# My JavaScript code works fine in Firefox, but not in chrome and IE

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

**JavaScript code**:  `common.js`

```
function setFocus(evt,data)
{
  var keycode=evt.keyCode;  
  $("[tabindex="+data[keycode]+"]").focus();
  return false; 
}
```

**PHP code**:

```
<table class="tblmenu">
   <tr>
      <td><div class="redbut"><a href="#" id="formstng"    tabindex="1" onKeyPress="setFocus(event,{'38':'5','40':'2'})">foT Aosa.Aona.Aof. laokTao saoTIMga </a></div></li></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><div class="redbut"><a href="#" id="setting" tabindex="2" onKeyPress="setFocus(event,{'38':'1','40':'3'})">roT saoTIMga</a></div></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><div class="redbut"><a href="#" tabindex="3" onKeyPress="setFocus(event,{'38':'2','40':'4'})">slaIpa saoTIMga</a></div></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><div class="redbut"><a href="#" tabindex="4" onKeyPress="setFocus(event,{'38':'3','40':'5'})">isasTma saoTIMga</a></div></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><div class="redbut"><a href="#"  tabindex="5" onKeyPress="setFocus(event,{'38':'4','40':'1'})">yauzr AonT/I</a></div></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

i have try to focus on link with arrow key.this is worked fine in firefox but not in chrome
and IE.
  Thanks in Advance..

Comment: ID attributes should be *unique*.

Comment: Also, you should use `evt.which` in jQuery for better compatibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please use evt.charCode instead evt.keyCode for IE, (i.e) u can use as follows,

```
  var keycode =  evt.keyCode? evt.keyCode : evt.charCode
```

Comment: `evt.which` in jQuery normalizes the event for all browsers.